# Duvida sobre o VsCode

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um exercicio cujo codigo é o seguinte:

```
import random
n1 = str(input ('Primeiro aluno:'))
n2 = str(input ('Segundo aluno:'))
n3 = str(input ('Terceiro aluno:'))
n4 = str(input ('Quarto aluno:'))
lista = [n1,n2,n3,n4]
escolhido = random.choice(Lista)
print('O aluno escolhido foi: {}'.format(escolhido))
```

no pycharm ele executa normalmente porém no vs code dá o seguinte erro:

> File "desafio019.py", line 2, in
>
> n1 = str(input ('Primeiro aluno:'))   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'oi' is not defined

Comment: a dica é:aprende a a lignuagem, não IDEs. O código acima tem um erro, a variável "lista" aparece com o nome "Lista". 
A sugestão é mesmo usar um editor de código, nçao uma IDE, e executar seus programas no terminal. Quando tiver segurança, aí pode passar a usar uma IDE - que então vai te ajudar, em vez de fazer um monte de mágica que te desvia do assunto principal.

Comment: em particular, se deu _esse_ erro que você postou, não foi _esse_ código que estava rodando. VOlte lá e veja direito como está o arquivo. Não há uma variável `oi` na linha 2.

Comment: Eu diria que o erro deu porque está executando o código no Python 2, utilizando a função `input()`.

Comment: Realmente eu tinha feito uma alteração na linha 7, onde a variavel 'lista' estava inicialmente com 'L'. Porém o que não esta dando certo, é que quando vou executar o programa a primeira variável recebe apenas números, quando coloco um nome, como no caso acima foi "oi" não da certo.

Comment: Vou estudar um pouco mais e ver no que estou errando, obrigado pelas dicas galera!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcos Wesley, o erro que reportou não é sobre o código descrito acima. O erro seria outro, já que na linha sete deveria começar com l minusculo. Depois de corrigir isso, no caso do seu código, como ele exige um prompt para responder as perguntas do "input", você deve executar o debug usando o python com terminal integrado, desta forma o vscode abre uma tela para acesso ao terminal, onde você responderá as perguntas obtendo o resultado esperado.